# BASH: How do I grab columns that are separated by more than one space only?

Tags: bash, awk, stdout

I'm trying to grab select values from the output of `protonvpn s`, but I can't get the correct values because some words have a space between them. I want to only split values if there is *more than one* consecutive space. I'm also only interested in receiving values in the second column.

`protonvpn s` produces an output of (for example)

```
Status:       Connected
Time:         0:34:07
IP:           888.888.888.888
Server:       CH-CA#1
Features:     Secure-Core
Protocol:     TCP
Kill Switch:  Enabled
Country:      United States
City:         None
Load:         34%
Received:     4.43 MB
Sent:         1.17 MB
```

If I try `vpn=$(protonvpn s |  column -s '\t' -t | awk '{print $2}' ) ; echo "$vpn"`
produces:

```
a
0:27:57
162.253.71.24
CH-CA#1
ures:
ocol:
Swi
ry:
y:
29%
3.33
:
```

If I try  `vpn=$(protonvpn s |  column -s '  ' -t | awk '{print $2}' ) ; echo "$vpn"` produces:

```
Connected
0:42:02
162.253.71.24
CH-CA#1
Secure-Core
TCP
Switch:
United
None
34%
4.75
1.32
```

I tried also replacing single spaces `' '` with a dash `(-)` by:

```
vpn=$(protonvpn s)
vpn_parsed=${vpn// /-}
echo "$vpn_parsed"
```

but it replaces all spaces instead of single spaces between words:

```
Status:-------Connected
Time:---------0:47:47
IP:-----------162.253.71.24
Server:-------CH-CA#1
Features:-----Secure-Core
Protocol:-----TCP
Kill-Switch:--Enabled
Country:------United-States
City:---------None
Load:---------34%
Received:-----4.92-MB
Sent:---------1.42-MB
```

and then I can't seem to grab any columns with the dash as a delimiter:

```
vpn_out="$vpn_parsed" | column -s '-' -t | awk '{print $2}'
echo "$vpn_out"

// Produces no output
```

I expect and want the output to be:

```
Connected
0:34:07
888.888.888.888
CH-CA#1
Secure-Core
TCP
Enabled
United States
None
34%
4.43 MB
1.17 MB
```

Would someone please help me figure this out? I'm not a very advanced Bash user and I can't seem to get this working at all. I'm not opposed to replacing the single spaces between words (like `United States`) with a dash or other character, but I really need to drop the first column and extra whitespace.

It might also be relevant to know that I will need this output in an array, separated by each line, not space. That way I can pull values, like country, like this:

```
echo ${vpn_arr[7]

// Outputs "United States"
```

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is not column 2, but all columns except column 1.  Is the output of protovpn tab separated?  If so, that makes it really easy: `cut -f 2-`.  If not, perhaps you want some variant of `awk '{$1=""}1'`

Comment: Or perhaps you just want `cut -b 15-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cat file` in place of `protonvpn s` which I don't have:

```
$ declare -A arr="( $(cat file | awk '{tag=val=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",tag); sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val); printf " [\047%s\047]=\047%s\047", tag, val}') )"

$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr=([Sent]="1.17 MB" [Features]="Secure-Core" [Country]="United States" ["Kill Switch"]="Enabled" [Server]="CH-CA#1" [Load]="34%" [Received]="4.43 MB" [IP]="888.888.888.888" [Protocol]="TCP" [Time]="0:34:07" [City]="None" [Status]="Connected" )

$ for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "$i --> ${arr[$i]}"; done
Sent --> 1.17 MB
Features --> Secure-Core
Country --> United States
Kill Switch --> Enabled
Server --> CH-CA#1
Load --> 34%
Received --> 4.43 MB
IP --> 888.888.888.888
Protocol --> TCP
Time --> 0:34:07
City --> None
Status --> Connected

$ echo "${arr[Country]}"
United States

$ echo "${arr[Received]}"
4.43 MB

$ echo "${arr[Kill Switch]}"
Enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vpn=$(protonvpn s | sed 's/^.*: *//' ) ; echo "$vpn"
```

Should do the trick, it replaces (s/) everything from start of the line (^.*) including any amount of spaces ( *) after a ':' with nothing (//).

Comment: I like this solution a lot because it has much less code and will work nicely as a one-liner in my script. Only downside is that it cuts the Time: line down to `18` instead of say `0:02:18`. For my solution, that is fine because I am not doing anything specific with the time value :)

Comment: Change `^.*` to `[^:]*`.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you could remove the beginning of each line until a `:` is encountered plus the following space characters:

```
protonvpn s | sed 's/^[^:]*: *//'
```

- `s/` substitute
- `^` match the beginning of the line
- `[^:]*` match any non-`:` characters
- `:` match a literal `:`
- `*` match any space characters
- `//` replace with nothing

To store the output into an array, you could use `mapfile`:

```
$ mapfile -t vpn_arr <<< $(protonvpn s | sed 's/^[^:]*: *//')
$ echo "${vpn_arr[7]}"
United States
```

Comment: This works great! I love that it's a concise and short piece of code. Ultimately, I ended up using this solution in my script because of the included `mapfile` command. It works perfectly, so thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use sed instead of awk:

```
protonvpn s | sed -r 's/\S+\s*//'
```

The idea is to remove all characters up to the first spaces, and then remove spaces aswell.

```
\S+     # Any non-whitespace character, repeated one or more
\s*     # Any white-space character, repeated one or more
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cut` command:

```
vpn=$(protonvpn s | cut -d':' -f 2,3,4)
```

the `cut` command cuts a string by the specified delimiter (-d option), the -f option specifies which substrings to return. as the second line of the output of `protonvpn s` is `Time: 0:34:07` we need to set the -f option to 2,3,4 in order to gobble up all the parts.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.